# Stretched Elastic Sheet with Horizontal Cut in Interior

Tags: solid-mechanics, elasticity

Given a rectangular finite elastic sheet $ABCD$ containing an arbitrary horizontal cut (or discontinuity) $EF$ in its interior. The edge $AB$ of the sheet is tethered but $CD$ is stretched by $\Delta$ such the horizontal cut is pulled down and "stretched open" as shown below.

[image]

I would like to determine the function $x = F(X)$ that maps any point $X$ in the unstretched configuration to a point $x$ in the stretched configuration, assuming the stretching of the sheet does not tear the horizontal cut any further. I am not interested in the stresses on the sheet only its deformation. I would also be satisfied with an approximate "strength of materials" type solution.

Comment: I guess that you could run a finite element simulation.

Comment: @Olumide What have you tried so far? Do you know what the governing equations are here?